# Is there a name for this construction of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I'm looking for information about a particular method of constructing graphs. Does anyone know its name or any literature in which it appears?

Let us characterize graphs as  $G:=(V,C)$. Here $V$ is the set of nodes, and $C \subseteq 2^V$ is the family of all sets that are connected in $G$. I know this characterization is a bit redundant , but it works best for the purpose of this definition.

For any $W \subseteq V$, I'm considering a graph in the form $(W, \{A \cap W: A \in C\})$

Comment: Induced subgraph?

Comment: Not really, as it is possible to add vertices through this construction.

Comment: What does $W\subseteq V$ mean, then?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misspoke. You can add edges (but obviously not vertices).

Alternatively, the same construction method can be described as: two vertices $v,w$ are connected with an edge iff there is a connected subgraph of $V$ such that $v$ and $w$ are the only vertices of $W$ that belong to it.

Comment: How about "induced subgraph of the transitive closure"?